# Dúvida para usar o Replace junto com o Inner Join

Tags: mysql, replace, inner-join

Estou usando o `Inner Join` para combinar duas tabelas:

```
SELECT eventos.colab_id, colaboradores.setor 
FROM colaboradores INNER JOIN eventos
ON colaboradores.id = eventos.colab_id
```

Até aí tudo bem, no entanto tenho casos em que preciso eliminar o carácter ***"*** de `eventos.colab_id`. O `REPLACE` faz isso, porém eu não estou sabendo usar o sintaxe junto com o `Inner Join`.

Comment: Não posso dar update, pois quero apenas consultar, sem alterar a tabela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não muda nada o JOIN na questão, pode aplicar o replace normalmente:

```
SELECT REPLACE( eventos.colab_id, '"', '') AS colabid, colaboradores.setor 
FROM colaboradores INNER JOIN eventos
ON colaboradores.id = eventos.colab_id
```

Se for na comparação:

```
SELECT eventos.colab_id, colaboradores.setor 
FROM colaboradores INNER JOIN eventos
ON colaboradores.id = REPLACE( eventos.colab_id, '"', '');
```

Agora, se for esse segundo caso é muito melhor consertar o banco e deixar o campo como numérico. Para tirar definitivamente as aspas:

```
UPDATE eventos SET colab_id = REPLACE( colab_id, '"', '');
```

e depois disso converter a coluna para inteiro, para evitar problemas.

Answer (score 1):

A função [REPLACE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php) do `MySql` possui a seguinte sintaxe:

> REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with)

Parâmetros:

1. A string
2. A string que deseja substituir
3. A string que irá substituir a ocorrência buscada do item 2

No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
    SELECT eventos.colab_id, REPLACE(eventos.colab_id,'"',''),  colaboradores.setor 
    FROM colaboradores INNER JOIN eventos
    ON colaboradores.id = eventos.colab_id
```

Se for na segunda tabela, fica assim:

```
   SELECT eventos.colab_id,  colaboradores.setor 
   FROM colaboradores INNER JOIN eventos
   ON colaboradores.id = REPLACE(eventos.colab_id,'"','')
```

**Referência:** https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php